# How to make firebase data read only once in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
readProductFromServer() {

    this.qS = this.afDatabase.list('product_table', ref => {

      return ref.limitToLast(1000) ;


    }).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key1: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
    this.qS.subscribe(values => {

    });
  }
```

How to make this code read only once. I searched on the internet and not get an answer to my code, some solution is available in StackOverflow  but not match  with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an observable, if you want to read your data only one time and don't get any new emissions of possible update, juste add `take(1)` in your operator chains:

```
this.qS = this.afDatabase.list('product_table', ref => {
    return ref.limitToLast(1000) ;
}).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key1: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
}).take(1);

this.qS.subscribe(values => {

});
```

It will take the first emission then complete the observable.